# Как убрать цепочку редиректа?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, apache, url

Суть задачи состоит в том, чтобы убрать цепочку редиректа. Сам я фронт и не особо разбираюсь в этом вопросе. Вижу, что редиректов уйма, нужно их минимизировать максимально, скорее всего куча костылей в правилах, но как решить проблему пока не знаю. Скрины с сервиса и .htaccess ниже:

[image: Скрин с сервиса]

[image: скрин с htaccess]

Comment: Для начала убей этот хтацес, зайти в пермалнки и пересохрани их. ВП сгенерить правильный.